# Are questions about ideas in preprints off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, policy, closed-questions

**Another note:** (Since the first one wasn’t heeded...) OK, so the question was closed again. My appeal below was to both sides of the issue, so even though five people sought fit to do otherwise, I’d ask those who think the question should be open not to reopen it before this discussion has proceeded. This shouldn’t be a war of votes but an exchange of opinions and arguments.

**Note:** While it was certainly one possible outcome of this discussion that the question would eventually be reopened, I was hoping that this would take place after a thorough discussion and hopefully some form of consensus on the criteria. I see now that (likely in connection with this post) the question has already been reopened. That was not my immediate objective (otherwise I would have voted to reopen it instead of posting here). I hope that we can keep this discussion here focussed on the general questions that this case brought up and not let it turn into an edit war about whether this particular question stays open or closed. I see there are already two new close votes. I think it would be most conducive to a principled discussion if everyone on either side of the issue would refrain from voting in either direction until the required discussion has taken place.

---

[Proof of some Riemann identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606592) was closed as “off-topic”: “This question is not about mathematics, within the scope defined in the [help center](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)”. As is unfortunately often the case, the notice is wrong and unhelpful, since that help center page gives no indication at all why this question would be considered off-topic.

I assume that the basis for the closure is [Is it ok to ask about the correctness of preprints of crank friendly topics?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290), and in particular [the by far most upvoted answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2291) to that question. (I couldn’t find any other basis; if there is one, please point it out.)

I don’t want to go into the question whether that’s an accepted policy (it says “Proposed policy” at the top, and not everything with lots of upvotes is a policy), because I mostly agree with it. Rather, I’d like to know whether people think that it applies and/or should apply to this particular sort of question. I don’t find it very clear or helpful in that regard. It gives several examples, but most of these are more or less obvious; for instance, “have you read X” is obviously not a question on mathematics.

The present question summarizes the argument of the preprint and points out specific ideas that seem interesting: “What I like about it is his analytic approach using the behaviour of general series at singular points. [...] In particular I want to point out his main result [...] What do you think?” That seems to be exactly what the proposed policy says how questions about such preprints should be asked: “In summary, focus your question on specific technical aspects of the work that you'd like clarification on. ”

At the time of closure, the question had $8$ upvotes and $2$ downvotes, so a majority of voters (even when including the close voters) thought that it was a good question. It doesn’t fall under any of the “BAD” examples given in the proposed policy:

- Despite the introductory sentence “I was wondering if anyone is aware of this proof”, it doesn’t ask “have you read it”.
- It doesn’t ask “is the proof correct” – to the contrary, it says the OP couldn’t find a flaw but presumes there is one.
- It doesn’t say “I don't understand the paper and don't want to spend time reading it, can someone verify that the author’s claim is correct?” – quite the opposite, it shows that the OP read the paper and in fact summarizes it for us so that we can comment on the approach without having to read it ourselves.

So my questions are:

- Does this question fall under this proposed policy? (My view would be that it doesn’t.)
- Should this question fall under this proposed policy? (My view would be that it shouldn’t.)
- If so, why?
- If so, should the proposed policy be updated to provide a clearer basis for deciding which posts about preprints are off-topic?

(Obviously, if the answer to the second question is negative, the question should be reopened.)

Comment: It's true that the author of the question made some effort, but at the end of the day it still seems like a basic "correctness" question, which is "bad" according to the policy you linked to. I don't get your point with 'It doesn’t ask “is the proof correct” – to the contrary, it says the OP couldn’t find a flaw but presumes there is one.' On the substance that's the same. Granted, it does show some maturity on the side of the person that asked, but I don't think that alone is enough.

Comment: @quid: What would I have to write instead of mentioning that "I presume there is an error" in order for you not to say what you wrote above? If I wouldn't have said "I presume there is an error", then most likely it would have been pointed out in full generality by someone else. So essentially I forestalled by pointing it out, so people can get right to the question. Now apparently people insinuate that me saying "I presume there is an error" is basically the same as me asking for its correctedness. I just want to show it and see if people find an error. To me it seems legit as mentioned.

Comment: @Diger as far as I am concerned there is no problem in the  formulation, it is a problem with the type of question itself. The point of my comment was to understand what joriki wants to express. Ultimately I think "Is this correct?" is the same as "Is there an error?"

Comment: Yes, I understand that and yes, "Is this correct?" and "Is there an error?" is actually the same. But that is not what this post is mainly about. When discussing proofs (and even simple other questions here on MSE), it essentially boils down to "is this correct?" even for homework questions. So that is for granted. I just want to discuss this work and in particular want people to point out as many "flaws" as they think they find, in order to turn the proof upside down.

Comment: @Diger there we isolated the problem. "I just want to discuss this work" is not an appropriate type of question. This site is not for discussing preprints. One can ask to the point questions about preprints. General calls for *discussions* are off-topic.

Comment: So where is one supposed to talk about these things if not on a Q&A board?!

Comment: @Diger: This is not a discussion board, it's a question-and-answer site.

Comment: @quid: Could you give an example of what you would consider a to-the-point question about this preprint? (That's not a rhetorical question, I'm genuinely interested.) Would "Do you find this approach [which is summarized in the question] promising?" have been to the point? Or "What reasons speak against pursuing this approach?"?

Comment: IMHO, "Do you find this approach promising" is an opinion-based question, and both questions you ask about, @joriki, puts math.se in the role of evaluating the merits of a pre-print, which I suspect is correctly off-topic.  However, I suspect that if there is one step, or two, that an OP doesn't understand, it would be appropriate to ask: I don't understand how the author went from *foo* to *fie* on page 2, tag (3)...".

Comment: The sort of questions related to preprints that are suitable for this site are precise questions about specific steps (possibly about the correctness of the step). The question "what do you think?" is basically never a suitable question. Questions about a preprint in the GM category that has not been published after this long are unlikely to lead anywhere interesting.

Comment: @amWhy: If the discussion here were to come to the conclusion that evaluating the merits of a pre-print should be considered off-topic, then that would be a candidate for amending the proposed policy. I don't think it currently says anything in that direction

Comment: I concur, @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: @joriki no I cannot do this for *this* preprpint because I have not studied the preprint and have absolutely no intention to do so (except somebody would pay me at a high hourly rate for it).

Comment: @quid: That is utterly ignorant. So just because this preprint is like 10years old, you say it is not worth to discuss? Even more so; not worth the time that is rather spent to defend why this kind of policy should not be touched?

Comment: @quid: Then not about this preprint. I'd be interested in your answer to my question above if you delete "about this preprint".

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: If "unlikely to lead anywhere interesting" were a criterion, many if not most of the questions on this site would have to be closed as off-topic. It's not the purpose of this site to advance research. The bulk of the questions are about well-known things that are certain not to lead to anything interesting. People should be allowed to ask about things, and if someone is not interested, they don't have to answer. The discussion should focus on the purpose of the proposed policy, which is not to ensure that questions on this site lead to something interesting.

Comment: Another thing I'd be genuinely interested to hear, based on how the discussion has been going so far, is what the people who are arguing that this question should be considered off-topic view to be the purpose of this policy.

Comment: @joriki Something like "In the proof of Theorem 2.3 the author A invokes Proposition 5.2 from Published Paper P by B. However, in PP by B the at the start of section 5 the assumption is made that all operator are self-adjoint.  However,  in the proof of Theorem 2.3 it is not mentioned that or why operator D to which this result is applied is self-adjoint. Is it true that D is self-adjoint (and if so why?) or is there a problem in the proof?"

Comment: @quid: I don't get your example. Either $D$ is evidently self-adjoint, so no mention about it is just fine or $D$ is not self-adjoint which is then just the kind of thing that would be pointed out in such a discussion and all is well. I don't seem to be seeing things like this, where theorems are manifestly wrongly applied in the current case; and if there is...well let's talk about it! Why do you rather spent your time with defending a policy that is obsolete in some cases or by answering the bulk of questions that are not gonna "lead anywhere" for sure...

Comment: @Diger: I think the suggested criterion here is not whether such things would come up in the discussion you're seeking, but whether your original question was this specific.

Comment: @Diger I gave an example of the type of question I would consider as legitimate. Indeed potential answers include: "The operator D is in general not self-adjoint (consider for example this case). The proof seems incomplete." "The operator D is self-adjoint. Here is why..." "The operator D is not self-adjoint. But in fact Prop 5.2 holds in general. See Remark 5.7 in PP." Or whatever might be the case. The point is that the question I sketch is clearly and narrowly scoped. (Of course the question could still be poor in other regards, also as actual Q it should contain more context.)

Comment: @Diger The only question you pose in the question joriki links to is "What do you think?"  That's the hallmark of a post that needs closure as being opinion based, in that "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."  It also needs focus, because you never nailed down the scope of the question "What do you think?"

Comment: @amWhy: "What do you think?" comprises the general accumulation of obvious considerations that any "mathematically thinking person" would automatically adhere to, when it comes to a scrutinous examination of a particular problem, similar to those considerations that are done when a person defends a specific general policy and comes to the conclusion that it is obsolete.

Comment: @Diger it is off-topic. You said you want to discuss the paper. This is exactly what the site is not intended for: it is not for discussion. This is one of the original cornerstones of SE: not for discussion.  Sorry, for the repetition. But if you want to make the point that we should allow discussion that's a non-starter. (This does not mean it is without merit in principle, but it's a non-starter on the main site; create a chat room if you want.)

Comment: @amWhy: Without taking any position in either direction on the content of your assessment: Note that "opinion-based" is a separate close reason from "off-topic". A majority of the close voters voted to close the question as "off-topic".

Comment: joriki  I commented to @Diger, not on your contention that the question is not off topic.  I contended, when addressing Diger, that their question could correctly be closed for many reasons. I did this because Diger is trying to defend on many grounds,  not just the specific close reason you object to in your OP. I'm not here to nitpick about the *best* close reason.  Again, also I will note now that you seem to primarily contest close reasons used to close questions that you've answered.  Just an observation.

Comment: Also note, Joriki, that there is a dedicated thread for you to do just that.

Comment: @Diger  To answer your comment/question: "So where is one supposed to talk about these things if not on a Q&A board?!"  Try doing so in a math.se chatroom, and see if there is up-take.  If not, or create your own chatroom, to discuss preprints, etc.. [See math.se chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).  Chat-rooms are far less structured and formal than the main site is.  Lots of discussions take place in lots of these chatrooms.

Comment: @joriki "This shouldn’t be a war of votes but an exchange of opinions and arguments."  Three people have added opinions and arguments, but just as in the post you don't think should be closed, both you and Diger have tried to dominate the "exchange of opinions and arguments" both there and here.  It strikes me that you and Diger don't take seriously the many points made in this post, and the main post. The "attack" mode you both exhibit is at odds with your stated objective "Another note". Note, there have now been 10 close votes cast on the post...

Comment: Only two of you thinking no consensus has been reached wrt the closure of the post.  It seems you are not in agreement with the consensus, but that doesn't mean there is no consensus.

Comment: @amWhy: I was sort of waiting for you to say that :-) Please note that $5$ people voted to reopen the post. Not everyone enjoys having discussions in this style, but their votes count nonetheless. By the way, two people not agreeing with the consensus does mean that there's no consensus, but I don't have much hope that we'll reach a consensus in this way anyway. (And as above I mean both "sides" by that.)

Comment: Still,  that's 10 to 5. A two-thirds mandate

Comment: @amWhy: I'm not sure what "still" refers to. Your argument was that there was a consensus. It was already flawed if there had been only two against it. Clearly there's no consensus when there's $\frac13$ against it. So there's no "still".

Comment: @amWhy: That's clearly false. There's a consensus (hopefully) among us that the Earth is not flat. The fact that that's only possible because I agree with it doesn't make it impossible.

Comment: What I take from this discussion is that we're using the word "consensus" with different meanings and have therefore mostly been talking past each other. Sorry if I contributed to wasting your time.

Comment: joriki  Sincerely, I would take your concerns expressed a tad more seriously if it was about an issue regarding a post that you had not answered.

Comment: @amWhy: It's good to know that you don't take my concerns seriously. I'll take that into account. I take your concerns seriously despite everything I dislike about your style. (For the benefit of readers who don't know the circumstances: I gave an embarrassingly flawed answer to that question and soon deleted it when the error was pointed out. So I have no reputation to gain from the post being reopened.)

Comment: I never said I don't take your concerns seriously, @joriki.   Since you are bent on distorting and twisting upside down, what I've said, you prove yourself unable to discuss this matter objectively, and so I'll no longer engage with you here.  As I said earlier, the only two users supporting your position are the asker and answerer of the question on main, which is the only basis for your question here.

Comment: @amWhy: I feel you don't understand what joriki is saying! Despite 2/3 of the (relatively active) MSE'ers voting to close this, it is by definition not a consensus in this case, because cutting "free and open speech" (which in this scope is with respect to mathematical questions) is never right!! It doesn't matter if the majority of people have a keen interest to do so and only allow what's within their personal scope of affection, because it gives leeway to ultimately disfranchising paternalism.

Comment: Anyway, you are right that this discussion doesn't lead anywhere, since it is "as you say" opinion based, and both sides will carry this opinion to open battle (including you!)!

Comment: @Diger consensus $\neq$ "everyone agrees"

Comment: @Diger: That wasn't exactly what I was saying :-) While I do think that minorities should have large weight on issues of closing questions (since to the minorities it means that their entire questions are closed and won't be answered, whereas to a closing majority, leaving them open "only" means having some unwanted questions in the question lists and search results) there does need to be some way of deciding what's on topic and what isn't, and in the end, if no consensus can be found, this will have to be decided by a majority (though hopefully respectful of the minority).

Comment: I left this comment on the question: On Mathoverflow, there is a long-established policy of not vetting papers, and this question would, accordingly, be closed. On math.stackexchange, I don't think there is any such policy, and the question makes a welcome change from the two thousand variations on "how do you differentiate $x^2$?" There is real mathematics in this question (even though the paper may well be worthless) and I'd like to see someone take a crack at it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I disagree with that there is no such policy. First, it's a consequence of "too broad" and it also came up explicitly more than once already on meta.

Comment: @quid: I'd be most obliged if you could link to previous discussions about this. I couldn't find anything other than the one I linked to and analyzed above.

Comment: For example see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29310/ // cc @Gerry

Comment: Or also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19653/ The thread also contains other views, *but* these other view mostly concern a case where the argument is in the question-post and thus "too broad" might not apply. (As is clear from that thread I am also convinced those should be not allowed, but the opinion on this aspect is maybe more mixed. But vetting preprints is clearly not in scope.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28692/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-07-2018-today)